# Is the Green-Tao theorem true for primes within a given arithmetic progression?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progression

Ben Green and Terrence Tao proved that there are arbitrary length arithmetic progressions among the primes.

Now, consider an arithmetic progression with starting term $a$ and common difference $d$. According to Dirichlet's theorem(suitably strengthened), the primes are "equally distributed" in each residue class modulo $d$. Therefore we imagine that the Green-Tao theorem should still be true if instead of primes we consider only those positive primes that are congruent to $a$ modulo $d$. That is, Green-Tao theorem is true for primes within a given arithmetic progression.

Question: Is something known about this stronger statement?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The Green-Tao is true for any subset of the primes of positive relative density; the primes in a fixed arithmetic progression to modulus $d$ have relative density $1/\phi(d)$.

Comment: can't argue with that....

Comment: Neither can I...

Comment: This is why I love Mathoverflow...

Comment: Well downvote me if you will, but I think the answer should say that the residue mod $d$ must be coprime to $d$, otherwise there is at most one prime in that residue class, so no nontrivial arithmetic progression in primes in that residue class.

Comment: @KoundinyaVajjha, I think that another reason to love MO is the exactly 256 upvotes (each) that Ben Green and Terry Tao got.

Comment: @LSpice It continues to this day