# A quadratic trinomial that generates only prime numbers of the form $4m+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

It is known that Euler's polynomials $\,n^2+n+p\,$ ($p\,$ prime) represent a prime for $\,n=0,\,...,\,p-2\,$ if and only if the field $\,Q (\sqrt{1-4p})\,$ has class number $\,h=1$.

The best trinomial of such kind is $\,n^2+n+41$.

> **But what we can say about quadratic trinomials that generate, for
>   consecutive values of their integer variable, only prime numbers of
>   the form $\,4m+1$?**

The best I could find out is the following trinomial:
$$p(n)=4\cdot(32\cdot(21-n)-n^2)+1$$
that generates prime numbers of the form $\,4m+1\,$ for $\,n=0,\,...,\,14$.

At the $2$-nd place, I would put the trinomial:
$$p(n)=4\cdot(n\cdot(64+n)-1171)+3$$
that generates (eventually in absolute value) prime numbers of the form $\,4m+1\,$ for $\,n=1,\,...,\,14\,$ and of the form $\,4m+3\,$ for $\,n=15,\,...,\,28$.

Every suggestion is well accepted.

Many thanks.

[ This question have been also posted on [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600024/a-quadratic-trinomial-that-generates-only-prime-numbers-of-the-form-4m1) ]

Comment: Using an extension of Green-Tao Theorem to polynomial patterns (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem#Extensions_and_generalizations)) you can show that there are trinomials which express arbitrarily long strings of primes. I suspect a generalization to primes in a fixed arithmetic progression would be immediate from the method of proof, [like for standard Green-Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25402/30186), but I can't speak with confidence.

Comment: Crossposted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600024/a-quadratic-trinomial-that-generates-only-prime-numbers-of-the-form-4m1).