# Does Pinelis' inequality (1994) exist?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I am reading a paper on stochastic optimization. And in this paper, the proofs are based on the Pinelis' 1994 inequality. I read the paper by Pinelis for more information and it is with great frustration that I was not able to find the inequality corresponding to that mentioned in the paper I am reading.

Here's the inequality in the article I'm reading:

$$ \begin{array}l
\text{(The Pinelis' 1994 inequality). Let } X_1,\dots, X_T \in \mathbb{R}^d \\ \text{be a random process satisfying } \mathbb{E}[X_t\mid X_1,\dots,X_{t−1} ] = 0 \text{ and} \\ \|X_t\| ≤ M. \text{ Then } \mathbb{P}[\| X_1 + \cdots + X_T\|^2 > 2 \log(2 /\delta)M^2T] \leq \delta.
\end{array}
$$

Nowhere in [Pinelis' 1994 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176988477) is this inequality mentioned.

So I ask myself, does this inequality really exist? Do you know it?

Comment: I am reading this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08917.pdf.
At Lemma 2.4

Comment: looks like theorem 3.5 in Pinelis (1994)

Comment: This is the same as Azuma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuma%27s_inequality, isn't it?

Comment: It is not the same as Azuma. Pinelis' inequality holds in any dimension (in fact, in Hilbert space) with no dependence on dimension.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As noted in Carlo Beenakker's comment, your inequality is a direct application of Theorem 3.5 in the linked paper: in that theorem, take $d_j=X_j$, $r=\sqrt{2M^2 T\ln(2/\delta)}$, $b_*^2=M^2T$, and $D=1$.

Comment: OHHH ! Okay Sir !

Comment: One of the things that I always liked about MathOverflow is the non-vanishing probability of getting first-hand anwers... :-)

Comment: @JochenGlueck [My personal favorite example.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25403/8133)